# Google Geocode api returning incorrect result for a particular address

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoder, geocode

When I try to geocode one of the adress using Google geocode api, Google api returns an incorrect location.

search address :  republic of estonia

result from google api:  spain

I am using javascript Google api to geocode the address. For some other location the result is correct but for above address its incorrect.

If we enter below url in browser, we get the JSON back and it is showing result somewhere in Spain rather than showing result in Estonia.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=republic%20of%20estonia

I tried same addres in maps.google.com and it takes me to correct location.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the Estonia country feature in Map Maker:

https://www.google.com/mapmaker?iwloc=0_0&fmi=0_0&gw=39&fid=5085290329182063613:4677726785527621059&dtab=overview&ll=58.620408,24.93212&spn=3.101226,8.668213&z=7&lyt=large_map_v3&htll=58.560236,25.449737&hyaw=278.7642140009582

If you check the list of names for this feature, you will see that there is no 'Republic of Estonia' in the list. The name is simply 'Estonia'.

The request for 'Estonia' works as expected:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=estonia&key=YOUR_API_KEY

If you believe that 'Republic of Estonia' must be in the list of the names please Send a feedback (bottom right corner) to Google from this page

https://www.google.com/maps/place/Estonia/@58.7223142,23.1414399,7z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x4692949c82a04bfd:0x40ea9fba4fb425c3!8m2!3d58.595272!4d25.013607?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Google assumed you were looking for "Calle Estonia" or "Estonia Street".

You [should request that Google](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list) add "Republic of Estonia" to their list of spaces. Google, and most other mapping services, only have "Estonia" or "EST" in their list of places.

---

Also, you may want to use a different API if you need to get an accurate answer. Google is really good, but Google tries to "guess" what you mean and always gives you a result. But, a service like [SmartyStreets](https://smartystreets.com/demo) matches searches to databases of addresses (so if the search is not a "real" place, it will tell you).

(Full disclosure: I have worked for SmartyStreets.)